# How to remove ghosting from refraction in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

I keep seeing this ghost of objects that are above my refraction plane. It seems to have to do with SSR not knowing what is under the cube, so it renders out a cube shaped gap that gets distorted as I adjust the IOR. Any suggestions on how to to workaround this?

edit: adding the Blend file

https://we.tl/t-nP9vwbIqnM

Comment: This need more details, your settings, what is that plane or even better your file with those specific objects

Comment: @MikoCG Apologies, here is the blend file https://we.tl/t-nP9vwbIqnM